Is my oc too similar to a fictional character, if so, What can I do to change it? Will I get hate?
I have an OC that looks very similar to Nimona: same hairstyle (kinda), matching personalities, and lots of spike/studded accessories.
I'm afraid that my OC is too similar, and that I'll have to change it, despite loving this design already.
The funny thing is that when I made this OC, I didn't even have Nimona in mind, and only realised the similarities after making the OC.
I understand that it might not be copyrighted or anything, but might get a lot of hate or trolls talking about how similar they are.
This OC will be used in an animation series, so I'm less worried about names and personality similarities (Considering there is no similarity in names) but I'm mainly worried about the design as it seems a bit too similar to pass as "Oh it's fine, it's just a little similar" Which is why I am worried. (Again, I did not realize how similar they were until creating the character.)

There is also a whole host of similar questions that you might find helpful.
